# Alternative to Prosody + Spectrum?

Tags: server, instant-messaging, xmpp

I'm running my own Prosody XMPP server, and I was using the Spectrum plug-in to provide gateways to the other instant-messaging services like AIM, MSN Messenger, Yahoo Messenger, etc.

Spectrum has been inactive for quite a while (last update was for Debian Sarge, IIRC), and it hasn't kept up with changes in proprietary instant-messaging protocols or security/encryption standards.

Googling for **Prosody** and **Spectrum** produces surprisingly few hits outside of their GitHub page, so I'm wondering whether there's one or more alternative ways to accomplish this that I've overlooked.

Does anyone else out there aggregate their messaging contacts from various services like this?